# Trying to solve $x^2 – 11x = y^2$ knowing that $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Once upon a time, I knew how to solve this equation. Yesterday, I tried (and failed) to solve it again. I remember the solutions, but I can't figure out how to find them…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can factor the equation by completing the square and clearing denominators and you end up getting

$$
(2x - 11 - 2y)(2x - 11 + 2y) = 121
$$

After this you can consider all possible factorizations of $121$, so you'll have to solve some systems of linear equations.

**Added in response to comments**

To factor the original equation by completing the square and clearing denominators you can do the following.

$$
\begin{align}
x^2 - 11x = y^2 &\iff x^2 - 11x - y^2 = 0\\
&\iff (x^2 - 11x \quad \quad \quad) - y^2 = 0\\
&\iff \left( x^2 - 11x + \color{red}{ \left( \frac{11}{2} \right)^2}  -  \color{red}{ \left( \frac{11}{2} \right)^2} \right) - y^2 = 0\\
&\iff \left( x^2 - 11x +  \color{red}{ \left( \frac{11}{2} \right)^2} \right) - y^2 = \color{red}{ \left( \frac{11}{2} \right)^2}\\
&\iff \left( x - \frac{11}{2}  \right)^2 - y^2 = \frac{121}{4}\\
&\iff \left( \frac{2x - 11}{2}  \right)^2 - y^2 = \frac{121}{4}\\
&\iff \frac{1}{4} (2x - 11)^2 - y^2 = \frac{121}{4}\\
&\iff \hspace{-2.0cm}\underbrace{(2x - 11)^2 - 4y^2}_{\text{Difference of squares, factors as $A^2 - B^2 = (A-B)(A+B)$}} \hspace{-2.0cm}= 121\\
&\iff (\underbrace{2x - 11}_{A} -\underbrace{2y}_{B})(2x - 11 + 2y) = 121
\end{align}
$$

The method's name is just [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), and you should google for this if you want more information. In fact you can find some online videos where the method is explained, like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGOQYTo9AKY).

Finally, yes, all you have to do after factoring the equation is considering the pairs of equations you mentioned $(2x - 11 -2y, 2x -11 + 2y) = (\pm 11, \pm 11), (\pm 121, \pm 1), (\pm 1, \pm 121)$. Just be careful that for some of these you may not get solutions (I only solved a couple of them so I don't know if all of them give integer solutions).

Comment: @Jean I added something to try to answer your questions. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Complete the square.${}{}{}{}$You may first want to multiply by $4$.